# How to print date in format «long» on node.html.twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, datetime

Try this code (at `node.html.twig`, Drupal 8.0.0-rc3):

```
{% set date = node.created|format_date('long') %}
```

And next:

```
{{ dump(date) }}
```

Return error:

```
Exception: The timestamp must be numeric. in Drupal\Component\Datetime\DateTimePlus::createFromTimestamp() (line 165 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Datetime/DateTimePlus.php).

Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatter->format(Object, 'long')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you are not using the actual timestamp. Here's what you should do:

```
{% set date = node.createdtime|format_date('long') %}
```

See? You only need to replace created with createdtime.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, this work.

Comment: And what variables, such as ``createdtime``, from ``node``? If I try ``{{ dump(node) }}`` — request is WSOD..

Comment: Use Kint. It's a sub module of the devel module.

Comment: createdtime is a twig style shortcut for the getCreatedTime() method. node.created is a FIeldItemList object, you can get the same value by accessing the value field property with node.created.value1format... Only base fields have methods, configurable fields need to be access like above.

Comment: {% set date = node.createdtime|format_date('long') %}
did not work for me. I had to use:
{% set date = node.createdtime|date('long') %}

Answer (score 5):

Try in this way.

```
{% set date = node.created %}
{{ set date|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

- Refer [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) to know more about filter date in **TWIG**.
- Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php.) to know more about **date formats in php**.

Hope this will help you.